# How to organize fields into 2 columns in a pageblocksection

Tags: visualforce, bootstrap

I have a custom vf page for the contact object. I need to seperate fields into 2 columns so it displays like this:

[image]

But it is adding the fields from left to right like so:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Member Information" collapsible="false">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Name}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Birthdate}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Gender__c}" />
                <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Active__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!SelectedPolicy.Policy__r.Reward_Status__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!SelectedPolicy.Policy__r.Points_Status__c}"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <apex:outputField label="Group" value="{!SelectedPolicy.Policy__r.Account__r.Name}" />
                <apex:outputField value="{!SelectedPolicy.Policy__r.Branch__c}" />
                <apex:outputField value="{!SelectedPolicy.Current_Effective_Date__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!SelectedPolicy.VITA_End_Date__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!SelectedPolicy.Policy__r.Account__r.Platform__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!SelectedPolicy.Role__c}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Comment: If you are using the page block section then there is no need to use the <div> and bootstrap classes. Use the standard page block component stuff. Choose one way or the other to handle the layouts for that section

Comment: But Bootstrap is so awesome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pageBlockSection component handles the ordering automatically as it is listed in the code. Each field is put into a cell until the number of defined columns is reached, which then starts the next row. The component also has it's own column attribute to define the number of columns to display (no need for grids). Something like below should get close to the desired output:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Member Information" collapsible="false" columns="2">
    <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Name}"/>
    <apex:outputField value="{!SelectedPolicy.Policy__r.Branch__c}" />
    <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Birthdate}"/>
    <apex:outputField value="{!SelectedPolicy.Current_Effective_Date__c}"/>
    <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Gender__c}" />
    <apex:outputField value="{!SelectedPolicy.VITA_End_Date__c}"/>
    <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Active__c}"/>
    <apex:outputField value="{!SelectedPolicy.Policy__r.Account__r.Platform__c}"/>
    <apex:outputField value="{!SelectedPolicy.Policy__r.Reward_Status__c}"/>
    <apex:outputField label="Group" value="{!SelectedPolicy.Policy__r.Account__r.Name}" />
    <apex:outputField value="{!SelectedPolicy.Policy__r.Points_Status__c}"/>
    <apex:outputField value="{!SelectedPolicy.Role__c}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Reference:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageBlockSection.htm

Comment: This is the standard way, but it's not allowing you to organize the fields into proper groups in your code.  Grouping them in code is what I am looking for.  Similar to what the OP posted in his page source.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this.

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Member Information" collapsible="false" columns="2">
 <apex:pageblocksectionitem>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Name}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Birthdate}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Gender__c}" />
                <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Active__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!SelectedPolicy.Policy__r.Reward_Status__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!SelectedPolicy.Policy__r.Points_Status__c}"/>
 </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
 <apex:pageblocksectionitem>
                <apex:outputField label="Group" value="{!SelectedPolicy.Policy__r.Account__r.Name}" />
                <apex:outputField value="{!SelectedPolicy.Policy__r.Branch__c}" />
                <apex:outputField value="{!SelectedPolicy.Current_Effective_Date__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!SelectedPolicy.VITA_End_Date__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!SelectedPolicy.Policy__r.Account__r.Platform__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!SelectedPolicy.Role__c}"/>
 </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

This would solve your problem. Just put the fields you want in left column inside the firt pageblocksectionitem, and the right column fields in other one.
Please mark as "Best Answer" if it solves your problem. Thanks

Comment: Cannot do this unless you wrap the outputfield blocks into <apex:outputPanel>.   And then it hides the labels, and even specifying the label attribute does not show them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a clever solution that actually works: [Visualforce layout prevent component column wrap](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13204/visualforce-layout-prevent-component-column-wrap)

It's simple - just set `columns="2"` on the main `apex:pageBlockSection`, and then add one nested `apex:pageBlockSection` with `columns="1"` for each column, containing the fields for that column.

Comment: This skews column alignment relative to other pageblocksections on the page.  Still no perfect solution...